# word usage Electricity charges or Electricity Rate

Tags: word-usage

i am curious to know about how to use this word. like 
should i go for **electricity charges** are high or **electricity rate**s are high?
Thanks.

Comment: In USA we would probably refer to the total monthly charges as "the/my _electric bill_" or "the/my _power bill_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which you use depends on what you mean. The "rates" are the prices per unit: so much per kilowatt-hour; the "charges" are the amounts actually charged, calculated as the amount used times the rate. So you could have high charges with low rates if you use a lot of electricity, or low charges with high rates if you use very little electricity. Or they could both be low, or both be high.

Comment: However, I would tend to keep my distance from someone who is "electrically charged".